# Could we please update the link to the Wheel of Blame on the Tavern?

Tags: support, chat, hyperlinks

Following the [link](http://bit.ly/pYtBLT) to the Wheel of Blame script welded on to the Tavern currently results in this:

[image]

Could the linked script be updated per the gentleman's request? [The script is widely available on CDNs](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.easing/1.3/jquery.easing.1.3.js), so this isn't too difficult. I realise this isn't a huge problem, since the link is rarely visited, but still:

1. The message was obviously prompted by bandwidth leakage, which is at least partly our fault
2. The link is in a relatively prominent place on the site, <s>which makes us look like a bunch of jerks</s> which may reflect poorly on the community

For the record, I did try to bring this up [in the chatroom](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1364510#1364510), but it seems to have become lost in the conversation.

Comment: Lies. It's just always Marc Gravell's fault so there's really no need to spin the wheel...

Comment: Isn't that an issue with JSFiddle?

Comment: @random no, the person who wrote the jQuery plugin used in the fiddle moved it to a CDN server. (the message in black background come from the plugin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/. You'll want a room owner to edit the description.

Comment: Room description updated.

Comment: Pssst. The fiddle needs the JS file updated from `http://` to `https://`.